# How to Load Resources (Css, js files) in Laravel 4 (Optimization)

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel-4

I searched for the similar question on stack over flow, but unable to find any.

I know how to load css and js files in laravel 4, but when we load these files using **asset()** method or throught HTML-Builder **HTML::script($url, $attributes);** everyone will have notice that it loads files something like that **http:// something/public/themeName/style.css**

I wonder, is there any way to load files, like we used to be **css/style.css**
Actually, i would like to reduce the number of HTTP requests done when loading a page.

**I know (css/style.css) will also fire an HTTP request but didn't it will took less time to load resources than "http:// something/public/themeName/css/style.css" ?**

**EDIT**

Sorry forget to mention, actually this method works fine "css/style.css" when we use it for only one page in laravel. But when we need to reload same files on diff pages in laravel, we use **asset()** and HTML Builders for that. which then loads these resources like "http:// appname/public/js/javascript.js"
But i would like to load it like we normally do (js/javascript.js).

Comment: So, you want to put all javascript and css directly in your header?

Comment: `href="css/style.css"` will fire an HTTP request nonetheless, it's just a relative path instead of an absolute

Comment: I understood from the beginning, I'm trying to tell you: it's the same. You always make an HTTP request for the resource.

Comment: If there is any difference in speed resolving absolute vs relative paths, it's so small it doesn't even need to be taken into consideration. I suggest you don't waste time on optimizing things that need no optimization, unless you have some profiling data that suggests otherwise.

Comment: what do you mean by without http request? It is getting loaded in the client side because of the request only.

Comment: this question is about "optimization"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"`href="css/style.css"` will fire an HTTP request nonetheless, it's just a relative path instead of an absolute."

Thank you @Damien Pirsy you are right, answering it myself so if someone looking to the similar issue might not get confused.